# SQL function causes Segfault on database server (MariaDB) when called twice

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using a MariaDB MySql server (version 10.4.13-MariaDB) on Arch Linux and I have managed to create a function that crashes the database whenever it is called for a second time (or at least it has never crashed the server upon the first use in my testing). 
No visible error is ever printed, the server just restarts, I've looked at `journalctl -e -u mariadb.service` but it is not of much help to me although it has let me to believe the crash is caused by a segmentation fault.

I have found some bug reports from 2005 which describe similar errors, but after closer inspection I don't think this is caused by the same issue. Can anybody please give me some clues as to what is going on here? It has been driving me crazy all day.

The SQL function is called `register_user` and looks like this:
It just performs a few checks regarding the validity of the provided invite code before adding a row to the `User` table.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE register_user(user_name TEXT, user_email TEXT, user_passw_hash TEXT, user_invite_code INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    -- Check: no previous use of email and invite code is still valid.
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = user_email
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Invite
        WHERE id = user_invite_code 
        AND valid_till > NOW()
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Invite.id, Invite.max_uses, COUNT(User.joined_with)
        FROM Invite
        LEFT JOIN User ON User.joined_with = Invite.id
        GROUP BY Invite.id, Invite.max_uses
        HAVING COUNT(User.joined_with) >= Invite.max_uses
    )

    -- If checks succeed insert values into users table and return true.
    THEN INSERT INTO User(email, name, passw_hash, joined_with)
        VALUES(user_email, user_name, user_passw_hash, user_invite_code);
        RETURN TRUE;

    ELSE RETURN FALSE;

    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Edit: I changed some of the function parameter names to be less confusing.

The following tables are used by the function:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Invite (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    valid_till TIMESTAMP,
    max_uses INT UNSIGNED
);

CREATE TABLE User (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '' UNIQUE,
    name TEXT,
    passw_hash TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    joined_with INT NOT NULL,
    joined_on TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (joined_with) REFERENCES Invite(id)
);
```

Output of `journalctl -e -u mariadb.service`:

```
jun 02 17:49:14 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.4.13 database server.
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: 200602 17:50:35 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: key_buffer_size=134217728
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: read_buffer_size=131072
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: max_used_connections=1
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: max_threads=153
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: thread_count=7
un 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: It is possible that mysqld could use up to
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467756 K  bytes of memory
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Thread pointer: 0x7f34e7807348
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: terribly wrong...
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: stack_bottom = 0x7f35254835b8 thread_stack 0x49000
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2a)[0x557ad1d044ea]
jun 02 17:50:35 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x578)[0x557ad181b9f8]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: sigaction.c:0(__restore_rt)[0x7f3526002960]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN7cleanupEb+0x2c3)[0x557ad165da93]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN7destroyEv+0x40)[0x557ad165def0]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN13st_select_lex7cleanupEv+0x6a)[0x557ad16c48ca]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN30subselect_single_select_engine7prepareEP3THD+0x3a)[0x557ad18ce64a]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN14Item_subselect10fix_fieldsEP3THDPP4Item+0x139)[0x557ad18ce0a9]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN9Item_cond10fix_fieldsEP3THDPP4Item+0x1b8)[0x557ad1852958]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN3THD16sp_fix_func_itemEPP4Item+0x2c)[0x557ad15890ec]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN3THD20sp_prepare_func_itemEPP4Itemj+0xf)[0x557ad158915f]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN20sp_instr_jump_if_not9exec_coreEP3THDPj+0x1e)[0x557ad15891be]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN13sp_lex_keeper23reset_lex_and_exec_coreEP3THDPjbP8sp_instr+0x114)[0x557ad158fdb4]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head7executeEP3THDb+0x8cc)[0x557ad158accc]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN7sp_head16execute_functionEP3THDPP4ItemjP5FieldPP11sp_rcontextP11Query_arena+0x53d)[0x557ad158cb7d]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN7Item_sp12execute_implEP3THDPP4Itemj+0x122)[0x557ad1838742]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN7Item_sp7executeEP3THDPbPP4Itemj+0x23)[0x557ad1838903]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN12Item_func_sp7val_intEv+0xa)[0x557ad189944a]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZNK12Type_handler14Item_send_tinyEP4ItemP8ProtocolP8st_value+0x18)[0x557ad176cb48]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN8Protocol19send_result_set_rowEP4ListI4ItemE+0xa5)[0x557ad156e5d5]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN11select_send9send_dataER4ListI4ItemE+0x4b)[0x557ad15d1d0b]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN10exec_innerEv+0xd14)[0x557ad167e4e4]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x25)[0x557ad167e755]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_jP8st_orderS9_S7_S9_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x138)[0x557ad167c8c8]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x154)[0x557ad167d394]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(+0x66c02c)[0x557ad160f02c]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x68c7)[0x557ad161d617]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_statebb+0x1c9)[0x557ad161fed9]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjbb+0x1d34)[0x557ad1622de4]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x105)[0x557ad1624625]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECT+0x1c6)[0x557ad1708936]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: /usr/bin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x33)[0x557ad1708a73]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: pthread_create.c:0(start_thread)[0x7f3525ff7422]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: :0(__GI___clone)[0x7f35257c7bf3]
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Trying to get some variables.
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Query (0x7f34e785fde0): SELECT register_user('matthijs', 'an@email.com', 'sdalioas', 1235) AS success
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Connection ID (thread ID): 8
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Status: NOT_KILLED
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_push>
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Writing a core file...
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Resource Limits:
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max core file size        unlimited            unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max processes             62581                62581                processes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max open files            16364                16364                files
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max pending signals       62581                62581                signals
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max nice priority         0                    0
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max realtime priority     0                    0
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
jun 02 17:50:36 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29155]: Core pattern: |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c ...
jun 02 17:50:37 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
jun 02 17:50:37 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 21.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.4.13 database server.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.4.13 database server...
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] /usr/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.13-MariaDB) starting as process 29410 ...
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16364 (request: 32194)
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2135060
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 2135069; transaction id 4666
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200602 17:50:42
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: 2020-06-02 17:50:42 0 [Note] /usr/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower mysqld[29410]: Version: '10.4.13-MariaDB'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Arch Linux
jun 02 17:50:42 LinuxIsPower systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.4.13 database server.
```

Comment: What are the size of the tables (number of records)? Also, did you try adding some prints interleaved? This may give you some indications if, for instance, the problem is in the `INSERT` or in the `SELECT`. Another check is to remove the Foreign Key and replace it with some other kind of link (say, a common sequence).

Comment: @FDavidov MySQL still does not have print statements and shell commands cannot be used inside of functions. The database is currently not in production so there are no records in the database apart from one row in the `Invite` table.

Comment: Side note: `invite_code INT` - this implies that your invite codes are autogen ids, and sequential.  That would mean that it's possible to guess invites from other people.  In general, such ids should never be exported outside of the database, or only to their owner (ie, only export `customer_id` to that customer's session).  Use some randomized id instead, like a UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database should not crash, that is correct. To improve your code (and possibly reduce the possibility of a crash), you could do following:

1. Use procedure instead of a function as what you do looks more like a procedure
2. Shoudn't the second check also include the `invite_code` passed in as parameter?
3. Fix the `GROUP BY` query as it does not seem to be correct
4. Do not use parameter names that match column names (like `name`)

Comment: I did the things you suggested, although I still have no idea which one(s) fixed my mystery bug after I came back from lunch the sql server stopped crashing. I guess the lesson here is that I shouldn't have been writing such messy code to begin with. Thanks for your help!